# Why does numpy.linalg.solve() offer more precise matrix inversions than numpy.linalg.inv()?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I do not quite understand why `numpy.linalg.solve()` gives the more precise answer, whereas `numpy.linalg.inv()` breaks down somewhat, giving (what I believe are) estimates.

For a concrete example, I am solving the equation `C^{-1} * d`  where `C` denotes a matrix, and `d` is a vector-array. For the sake of discussion, the dimensions of `C` are shape `(1000,1000)` and `d` is shape `(1,1000)`.

`numpy.linalg.solve(A, b)` solves the equation `A*x=b` for x, i.e. `x = A^{-1} * b.` Therefore, I could either solve this equation by

(1)

```
inverse = numpy.linalg.inv(C)
result = inverse * d
```

or (2)

```
numpy.linalg.solve(C, d)
```

Method (2) gives far more precise results. Why is this?

What exactly is happening such that one "works better" than the other?

Comment: Best pick up a textbook. Golub and van Loan would be a good choice.

Comment: Just a guess ( possibly from somewhere of Gilbert Strang Books) : I think the inverse is never really calculated during the call of the underlying LAPACK routine. What if you try pinv() instead of inv() ? Look at the reference of pinv()

Comment: In most cases, linear equation solution is faster and produces less round-off error than inversion and multiplication.  Fundamentally, these are operations on "floating" number representations, not the real numbers themselves.

Comment: Would be interesting to knoe the comparison of pinv wth solve

Comment: You almost *never* want to compute the inverse of a matrix... it's inefficient, and the error is generally higher than other methods.

Comment: @Bakuriu Let's not go through this again :) Yes, I realize that you usually don't want to, but there are times when you would. Many of the algorithms I can think of come from computational statistics, when there is no other option available.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`np.linalg.solve(A, b)` does *not* compute the inverse of *A*. Instead it calls one of the [`gesv` LAPACK routines](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgesv.f), which first factorizes *A* using LU decomposition, then solves for *x* using forward and backward substitution (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Solving_linear_equations)).

`np.linalg.inv` uses the same method to compute the inverse of *A* by solving for *A<sup>-1</sup>* in *A·A<sup>-1</sup> = I* where *I* is the identity*. The factorization step is exactly the same as above, but it takes more floating point operations to solve for *A<sup>-1</sup>* (an *n×n* matrix) than for *x* (an *n*-long vector). Additionally, if you then wanted to obtain *x* via the identity *A<sup>-1</sup>·b = x* then the extra matrix multiplication would incur yet more floating point operations, and therefore slower performance and more numerical error.

There's no need for the intermediate step of computing *A<sup>-1</sup>* - it is  faster and more accurate to obtain *x* directly.

---

* The relevant bit of source for `inv` is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L1727-L1729). Unfortunately it's a bit tricky to understand since it's templated C. The important thing to note is that an identity matrix is being passed to the LAPACK solver as parameter `B`.