# Normal equation and Numpy 'least-squares', 'solve' methods difference in regression?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-algebra, linear-regression

I am doing linear regression with multiple variables/features. I try to get thetas (coefficients) by using **normal equation** method (that uses matrix inverse), Numpy least-squares [**numpy.linalg.lstsq**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) tool and [**np.linalg.solve**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) tool. In my data I have **n = 143** features and **m = 13000** training examples.

---

For **normal equation** method with **regularization** I use this formula:

> [image]
>   *Sources*:
>
> - [*Regularization (Andrew Ng, Stanford)*](http://csns.calstatela.edu/download?fileId=4952741)
> - [*Normal equations (Andrew Ng, Stanford*)](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex5/ex5.html)

*Regularization is used to solve the potential problem of matrix non-invertibility (`XtX` matrix may become singular/non-invertible)*

---

**Data preparation code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = 'DB2.csv'  
data = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, delimiter=";")

data.insert(0, 'Ones', 1)
cols = data.shape[1]

X = data.iloc[:,0:cols-1]  
y = data.iloc[:,cols-1:cols] 

IdentitySize = X.shape[1]
IdentityMatrix= np.zeros((IdentitySize, IdentitySize))
np.fill_diagonal(IdentityMatrix, 1)
```

---

For **least squares** method I use Numpy's *numpy.linalg.lstsq*. Here is Python code:

```
lamb = 1
th = np.linalg.lstsq(X.T.dot(X) + lamb * IdentityMatrix, X.T.dot(y))[0]
```

Also I used **np.linalg.solve** tool of numpy:

```
lamb = 1
XtX_lamb = X.T.dot(X) + lamb * IdentityMatrix
XtY = X.T.dot(y)
x = np.linalg.solve(XtX_lamb, XtY);
```

For **normal equation** I use:

```
lamb = 1
xTx = X.T.dot(X) + lamb * IdentityMatrix
XtX = np.linalg.inv(xTx)
XtX_xT = XtX.dot(X.T)
theta = XtX_xT.dot(y)
```

---

In all methods I used regularization. Here is results (theta coefficients) to see difference between these three approaches:

```
Normal equation:        np.linalg.lstsq         np.linalg.solve
[-27551.99918303]       [-27551.95276154]       [-27551.9991855]
[-940.27518383]         [-940.27520138]         [-940.27518383]
[-9332.54653964]        [-9332.55448263]        [-9332.54654461]
[-3149.02902071]        [-3149.03496582]        [-3149.02900965]
[-1863.25125909]        [-1863.2631435]         [-1863.25126344]
[-2779.91105618]        [-2779.92175308]        [-2779.91105347]
[-1226.60014026]        [-1226.61033117]        [-1226.60014192]
[-920.73334259]         [-920.74331432]         [-920.73334194]
[-6278.44238081]        [-6278.45496955]        [-6278.44237847]
[-2001.48544938]        [-2001.49566981]        [-2001.48545349]
[-715.79204971]         [-715.79664124]         [-715.79204921]
[ 4039.38847472]        [ 4039.38302499]        [ 4039.38847515]
[-2362.54853195]        [-2362.55280478]        [-2362.54853139]
[-12730.8039209]        [-12730.80866036]       [-12730.80392076]
[-24872.79868125]       [-24872.80203459]       [-24872.79867954]
[-3402.50791863]        [-3402.5140501]         [-3402.50793382]
[ 253.47894001]         [ 253.47177732]         [ 253.47892472]
[-5998.2045186]         [-5998.20513905]        [-5998.2045184]
[ 198.40560401]         [ 198.4049081]          [ 198.4056042]
[ 4368.97581411]        [ 4368.97175688]        [ 4368.97581426]
[-2885.68026222]        [-2885.68154407]        [-2885.68026205]
[ 1218.76602731]        [ 1218.76562838]        [ 1218.7660275]
[-1423.73583813]        [-1423.7369068]         [-1423.73583793]
[ 173.19125007]         [ 173.19086525]         [ 173.19125024]
[-3560.81709538]        [-3560.81650156]        [-3560.8170952]
[-142.68135768]         [-142.68162508]         [-142.6813575]
[-2010.89489111]        [-2010.89601322]        [-2010.89489092]
[-4463.64701238]        [-4463.64742877]        [-4463.64701219]
[ 17074.62997704]       [ 17074.62974609]       [ 17074.62997723]
[ 7917.75662561]        [ 7917.75682048]        [ 7917.75662578]
[-4234.16758492]        [-4234.16847544]        [-4234.16758474]
[-5500.10566329]        [-5500.106558]          [-5500.10566309]
[-5997.79002683]        [-5997.7904842]         [-5997.79002634]
[ 1376.42726683]        [ 1376.42629704]        [ 1376.42726705]
[ 6056.87496151]        [ 6056.87452659]        [ 6056.87496175]
[ 8149.0123667]         [ 8149.01209157]        [ 8149.01236827]
[-7273.3450484]         [-7273.34480382]        [-7273.34504827]
[-2010.61773247]        [-2010.61839251]        [-2010.61773225]
[-7917.81185096]        [-7917.81223606]        [-7917.81185084]
[ 8247.92773739]        [ 8247.92774315]        [ 8247.92773722]
[ 1267.25067823]        [ 1267.24677734]        [ 1267.25067832]
[ 2557.6208133]         [ 2557.62126916]        [ 2557.62081337]
[-5678.53744654]        [-5678.53820798]        [-5678.53744647]
[ 3406.41697822]        [ 3406.42040997]        [ 3406.41697836]
[-8371.23657044]        [-8371.2361594]         [-8371.23657035]
[ 15010.61728285]       [ 15010.61598236]       [ 15010.61728304]
[ 11006.21920273]       [ 11006.21711213]       [ 11006.21920284]
[-5930.93274062]        [-5930.93237071]        [-5930.93274048]
[-5232.84459862]        [-5232.84557665]        [-5232.84459848]
[ 3196.89304277]        [ 3196.89414431]        [ 3196.8930428]
[ 15298.53309912]       [ 15298.53496877]       [ 15298.53309919]
[ 4742.68631183]        [ 4742.6862601]         [ 4742.68631172]
[ 4423.14798495]        [ 4423.14765013]        [ 4423.14798546]
[-16153.50854089]       [-16153.51038489]       [-16153.50854123]
[-22071.50792741]       [-22071.49808389]       [-22071.50792408]
[-688.22903323]         [-688.2310229]          [-688.22904006]
[-1060.88119863]        [-1060.8829114]         [-1060.88120546]
[-101.75750066]         [-101.75776411]         [-101.75750831]
[ 4106.77311898]        [ 4106.77128502]        [ 4106.77311218]
[ 3482.99764601]        [ 3482.99518758]        [ 3482.99763924]
[-1100.42290509]        [-1100.42166312]        [-1100.4229119]
[ 20892.42685103]       [ 20892.42487476]       [ 20892.42684422]
[-5007.54075789]        [-5007.54265501]        [-5007.54076473]
[ 11111.83929421]       [ 11111.83734144]       [ 11111.83928704]
[ 9488.57342568]        [ 9488.57158677]        [ 9488.57341883]
[-2992.3070786]         [-2992.29295891]        [-2992.30708529]
[ 17810.57005982]       [ 17810.56651223]       [ 17810.57005457]
[-2154.47389712]        [-2154.47504319]        [-2154.47390285]
[-5324.34206726]        [-5324.33913623]        [-5324.34207293]
[-14981.89224345]       [-14981.8965674]        [-14981.89224973]
[-29440.90545197]       [-29440.90465897]       [-29440.90545704]
[-6925.31991443]        [-6925.32123144]        [-6925.31992383]
[ 104.98071593]         [ 104.97886085]         [ 104.98071152]
[-5184.94477582]        [-5184.9447972]         [-5184.94477792]
[ 1555.54536625]        [ 1555.54254362]        [ 1555.5453638]
[-402.62443474]         [-402.62539068]         [-402.62443718]
[ 17746.15769322]       [ 17746.15458093]       [ 17746.15769074]
[-5512.94925026]        [-5512.94980649]        [-5512.94925267]
[-2202.8589276]         [-2202.86226244]        [-2202.85893056]
[-5549.05250407]        [-5549.05416936]        [-5549.05250669]
[-1675.87329493]        [-1675.87995809]        [-1675.87329255]
[-5274.27756529]        [-5274.28093377]        [-5274.2775701]
[-5424.10246845]        [-5424.10658526]        [-5424.10247326]
[-1014.70864363]        [-1014.71145066]        [-1014.70864845]
[ 12936.59360437]       [ 12936.59168749]       [ 12936.59359954]
[ 2912.71566077]        [ 2912.71282628]        [ 2912.71565599]
[ 6489.36648506]        [ 6489.36538259]        [ 6489.36648021]
[ 12025.06991281]       [ 12025.07040848]       [ 12025.06990358]
[ 17026.57841531]       [ 17026.56827742]       [ 17026.57841044]
[ 2220.1852193]         [ 2220.18531961]        [ 2220.18521579]
[-2886.39219026]        [-2886.39015388]        [-2886.39219394]
[-18393.24573629]       [-18393.25888463]       [-18393.24573872]
[-17591.33051471]       [-17591.32838012]       [-17591.33051834]
[-3947.18545848]        [-3947.17487999]        [-3947.18546459]
[ 7707.05472816]        [ 7707.05577227]        [ 7707.0547217]
[ 4280.72039079]        [ 4280.72338194]        [ 4280.72038435]
[-3137.48835901]        [-3137.48480197]        [-3137.48836531]
[ 6693.47303443]        [ 6693.46528167]        [ 6693.47302811]
[-13936.14265517]       [-13936.14329336]       [-13936.14267094]
[ 2684.29594641]        [ 2684.29859601]        [ 2684.29594183]
[-2193.61036078]        [-2193.63086307]        [-2193.610366]
[-10139.10424848]       [-10139.11905454]       [-10139.10426049]
[ 4475.11569903]        [ 4475.12288711]        [ 4475.11569421]
[-3037.71857269]        [-3037.72118246]        [-3037.71857265]
[-5538.71349798]        [-5538.71654224]        [-5538.71349794]
[ 8008.38521357]        [ 8008.39092739]        [ 8008.38521361]
[-1433.43859633]        [-1433.44181824]        [-1433.43859629]
[ 4212.47144667]        [ 4212.47368097]        [ 4212.47144686]
[ 19688.24263706]       [ 19688.2451694]        [ 19688.2426368]
[ 104.13434091]         [ 104.13434349]         [ 104.13434091]
[-654.02451175]         [-654.02493111]         [-654.02451174]
[-2522.8642551]         [-2522.88694451]        [-2522.86424254]
[-5011.20385919]        [-5011.22742915]        [-5011.20384655]
[-13285.64644021]       [-13285.66951459]       [-13285.64642763]
[-4254.86406891]        [-4254.88695873]        [-4254.86405637]
[-2477.42063206]        [-2477.43501057]        [-2477.42061727]
[ 0.]                   [  1.23691279e-10]      [ 0.]
[-92.79470071]          [-92.79467095]          [-92.79470071]
[ 2383.66211583]        [ 2383.66209637]        [ 2383.66211583]
[-10725.22892185]       [-10725.22889937]       [-10725.22892185]
[ 234.77560283]         [ 234.77560254]         [ 234.77560283]
[ 4739.22119578]        [ 4739.22121432]        [ 4739.22119578]
[ 43640.05854156]       [ 43640.05848841]       [ 43640.05854157]
[ 2592.3866707]         [ 2592.38671547]        [ 2592.3866707]
[-25130.02819215]       [-25130.05501178]       [-25130.02819515]
[ 4966.82173096]        [ 4966.7946407]         [ 4966.82172795]
[ 14232.97930665]       [ 14232.9529959]        [ 14232.97930363]
[-21621.77202422]       [-21621.79840459]       [-21621.7720272]
[ 9917.80960029]        [ 9917.80960571]        [ 9917.80960029]
[ 1355.79191536]        [ 1355.79198092]        [ 1355.79191536]
[-27218.44185748]       [-27218.46880642]       [-27218.44185719]
[-27218.04184348]       [-27218.06875423]       [-27218.04184318]
[ 23482.80743869]       [ 23482.78043029]       [ 23482.80743898]
[ 3401.67707434]        [ 3401.65134677]        [ 3401.67707463]
[ 3030.36383274]        [ 3030.36384909]        [ 3030.36383274]
[-30590.61847724]       [-30590.63933424]       [-30590.61847706]
[-28818.3942685]        [-28818.41520495]       [-28818.39426833]
[-25115.73726772]       [-25115.7580278]        [-25115.73726753]
[ 77174.61695995]       [ 77174.59548773]       [ 77174.61696016]
[-20201.86613672]       [-20201.88871113]       [-20201.86613657]
[ 51908.53292209]       [ 51908.53446495]       [ 51908.53292207]
[ 7710.71327865]        [ 7710.71324194]        [ 7710.71327865]
[-16206.9785119]        [-16206.97851993]       [-16206.9785119]
```

As you can see normal equation, least squares and np.linalg.solve tool methods give to some extent different results. The question is why these three approaches gives noticeably different results and which method gives **more efficient** and **more accurate** result?

**Assumption:**
Results of Normal equation method and results of **np.linalg.solve** are very close to each other. And results of **np.linalg.lstsq** differ from both of them. Since normal equation uses inverse we do not expect very accurate results of it and therefore results of np.linalg.solve tool also. Seem to be that better results are given by **np.linalg.lstsq**.

---

**Upd:**
*As **Dave Hensley** mentioned:*
*After the line* `np.fill_diagonal(IdentityMatrix, 1)` 
*this code* `IdentityMatrix[0,0] = 0` *should be added.*

---

***DB2.csv*** is available on DropBox: [DB2.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3pd7fp0rfm1cfs/DB2.csv?dl=0)

*Full Python code is available on DropBox: [Full code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0xq34fuxc51ffj/regression.py?dl=0)*

Comment: Out of curiosity, is DB2.csv anywhere we can download?

Comment: I uploaded DB2.csv to google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzzUvSbpsTAvN1UxTkxXd2U0eVE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As **@Matthew Gunn** mentioned, it's bad practice to compute the explicit inverse of your coefficient matrix as a means to solve linear systems of equations. It's faster and more accurate to obtain the solution directly ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31256252/1461210)).

The reason why you see differences between `np.linalg.solve` and `np.linalg.lstsq` is because these functions make different assumptions about the system you are trying to solve, and use different numerical methods.

- Under the hood, `solve` calls the [DGESV LAPACK routine](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html#ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512), which uses LU factorization, followed by forward and backward substitution to find an *exact* solution to `Ax = b`. It requires that the system is exactly determined, i.e. that `A` is square and of full rank.
- `lstsq` instead calls [DGELSD](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga479cdaa0d257e4e42f2fb5dcc30111b1.html#ga479cdaa0d257e4e42f2fb5dcc30111b1), which uses the singular value decomposition of `A` in order to find a *least-squares* solution. This also works in overdetermined and underdetermined cases.

If your system is fully determined then you should use `solve` since it requires fewer floating point operations, and will therefore be faster and more precise. In your case, `XtX_lamb` is guaranteed to be full rank because of the regularisation step.

Answer (score 20):

#### Don't calculate matrix inverse to solve linear systems

The professional algorithms don't solve for the matrix inverse. It's slow and introduces unnecessary error. It's not a disaster for small systems, but why do something suboptimal?

Basically anytime you see the math written as:

```
x = A^-1 * b
```

you instead want:

```
x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
```

In you case, you want something like:

```
XtX_lamb = X.T.dot(X) + lamb * IdentityMatrix
XtY = X.T.dot(Y)
x = np.linalg.solve(XtX_lamb, XtY);
```

Comment: np.linalg.lstsq tool of Numpy does not use inverse for solving equations. I used np.linalg.lstsq and your suggestion np.linalg.solve. They both give different results. What is more efficient and accurate method np.linalg.solve or np.linalg.lstsq?

Comment: I updated question to see difference of three approaches.

Comment: Another way to see how different two vectors x1 and x2 are is to subtract x2 from x1 then take the norm using [numpy.linalg.norm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html).

Comment: One interesting thing is that results of np.linalg.solve tool are actually closer to Normal equation results that use inverse. Seem to be that better results are given by np.linalg.lstsq.

Comment: @MatthewGunn How would you change this if the data is complex and you wanted to conjugate multiply?

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 For complex matrices, a number of formulas involve the [conjugate transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.H.html) rather than the simple transpose .T. I believe everything should go through with complex values in numpy (eg. it should do something like calling LAPACK cgesv instead of dgesv), but I honestly don't know all the details or if there are any issues off the top of my head without spending some time on it.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers define why in theory one calculation method is better than to other. However they don't give a way to test which solution actually shows better results. Here it is:

```
def test(a, x, b):
    res = a.dot(x).as_matrix() - b.as_matrix()
    print(np.linalg.norm(res))

test(XtX_lamb, x, XtY)
test(XtX_lamb, th, XtY)
test(XtX_lamb, theta, XtY)
```

This calcluates the norm2 of the error vector of the linear system.
Results are:

```
np.linalg.solve - 0.000488340357871
np.linalg.lstsq - 1.75520748498
normal equation - 16.1628614202
```

Thus linalg.solve indeed show the most accurate result.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have a bug in your implementation which is affecting all 3 calculations. You use the following code to generate IdentityMatrix:

```
IdentityMatrix= np.zeros((IdentitySize, IdentitySize))
np.fill_diagonal(IdentityMatrix, 1)
```

(you could actually simplify that as `IdentityMatrix=np.eye(IdentitySize)`)

The identity matrix is this (when IdentitySize == 3):

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

But what you should be using is this (same thing but with 0 in the top left):

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```