# How to solve non-square system of linear equations?

Tags: python, numpy, math

**Question could be DUPLICATE.**

I'am trying to solve systems of linear equations using NumPy, and i face situations, when system is non-square. It can have infinite solutions, or no solutions. What is the way to handle these kind of situations to show no solution or infinite solutions outcome?

I've seen here the way, by using

```
np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)[0]
```

This method uses Least Square method, that is not helpful in my condition.

Comment: it usually depends on what for the solution is used...

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377331/solving-ax-b-for-a-non-square-matrix-a-using-python) ?

Comment: If you have more equations than unknowns, you use least squares regression.  If you have more unknowns than equations, you use singular value decomposition.