# Increasing the precision of numpy.linalg operations

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I'm trying to perform generalized least-squares fitting of highly correlated data. The covariance matrix for these data is large, with many elements close to 1.

```
# X and Y correspond to my predictor and dependent variables
# C is the covariance matrix of Y
# BF are the best-fit parameters
# BFCM is the covariance matrix of BF

from pylab import *

BF = inv(X.T @ inv(C) @ X) @ (X.T @ inv(C) @ Y)
BFCM = inv(X.T @ inv(C) @ X)
```

I'm getting negative diagonal terms in the correlation matrix of the best-fit parameters (`BFCM`), which is definitely wrong. It seems likely that these negative values come from the limited `float` precision used by `numpy.linalg`. Is there a way to avoid such floating point precision problems in this case?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Use `numpy.linalg.solve` to start with instead of inverses.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that as soon as I can. May I ask why you're suggesting it?

Comment: @Mathieu, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256252/why-does-numpy-linalg-solve-offer-more-precise-matrix-inversions-than-numpy-li

Comment: @percusse, I tried using `invC = solve(C, eye(C.shape[0]))`; `BFCM = solve(X.T @ invC @ X, eye(2))`; `BF = BFCM @ X.T @ invC @ Y`, but I still get rubbish values for the best-fit parameters. Is this what you were suggesting, or did I misunderstand?