# Computing `AB⁻¹` with `np.linalg.solve()`

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I need to compute `AB⁻¹` in Python / Numpy for two matrices `A` and `B` (`B` being square, of course).

I know that `np.linalg.inv()` would allow me to compute `B⁻¹`, which I can then multiply with `A`.
I also know that `B⁻¹A` is actually [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256252/why-does-numpy-linalg-solve-offer-more-precise-matrix-inversions-than-numpy-li) computed with `np.linalg.solve()`.

Inspired by that, I decided to rewrite `AB⁻¹` in terms of `np.linalg.solve()`.
I got to a formula, based on the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) `(AB)ᵀ = BᵀAᵀ`, which uses `np.linalg.solve()` and `.transpose()`:

```
np.linalg.solve(a.transpose(), b.transpose()).transpose()
```

that seems to be doing the job:

```
import numpy as np


n, m = 4, 2
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.random((n, n))
b = np.random.random((m, n))

print(np.matmul(b, np.linalg.inv(a)))
# [[ 2.87169378 -0.04207382 -1.10553758 -0.83200471]
#  [-1.08733434  1.00110176  0.79683577  0.67487591]]
print(np.linalg.solve(a.transpose(), b.transpose()).transpose())
# [[ 2.87169378 -0.04207382 -1.10553758 -0.83200471]
#  [-1.08733434  1.00110176  0.79683577  0.67487591]]
print(np.all(np.isclose(np.matmul(b, np.linalg.inv(a)), np.linalg.solve(a.transpose(), b.transpose()).transpose())))
# True
```

and also comes up much faster for sufficiently large inputs:

```
n, m = 400, 200
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.random((n, n))
b = np.random.random((m, n))

print(np.all(np.isclose(np.matmul(b, np.linalg.inv(a)), np.linalg.solve(a.transpose(), b.transpose()).transpose())))
# True

%timeit np.matmul(b, np.linalg.inv(a))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 13.3 ms per loop
%timeit np.linalg.solve(a.transpose(), b.transpose()).transpose()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 7.71 ms per loop
```

---

My question is: does this identity **always** stand correct *or* there are some corner cases I am overlooking?

Comment: as long `a` is not singular I dont see a problem

Comment: Btw, there are a couple of things you can do to make your code more succinct and readable: 1) use `a.T` instead of `a.transpose()`, and 2) use the `@` operator for matrix multiplication instead of `np.matmul()`. So your check would be `np.allclose(b @ a.T, np.linalg.solve(a.T, b.T).T)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, [`np.linalg.solve(B, A)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) is equivalent to `B-1A`. The rest is just math.

In all cases, `(AB)T = BTAT`: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1440305/295281.

Not necessary for this case, but for invertible matrices, `(AB)-1 = B-1A-1`: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/688339/295281.

For an invertible matrix, it is also the case that `(A-1)T = (AT)-1`: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/340233/295281.

From that it follows that `(AB-1)T = (B-1)TAT = (BT)-1AT`. As long as `B` is invertible, you should have no issues with the transformation you propose in any case.

Comment: I am not sure why do we need `(AB)⁻¹ = B⁻¹A⁻¹`. For the rest, that was precisely my line of thinking.

Comment: @norok2. For good measure :). I added it before I realized that I wasn't going to use it. I left it in because it doesn't hurt. I prefixed it with a note now.