# Matrix Algebra – is this implementation correct?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to learn how to use matrix algebra in Python and in order to do this I decided to implement Maximum Sharpe ratio formula given below

[image]

This is my implementation of the formula

```
def maximum_sharpe_ratio(cov, posterior_returns, risk_free_rate):
    risk_free_vector = np.ones(len(posterior_returns)) * risk_free_rate
    inv_cov = np.linalg.inv(cov)
    numerator = np.dot(inv_cov, posterior_returns - risk_free_vector)
    denominator = np.dot(np.ones(len(posterior_returns)), np.dot(np.linalg.inv(cov), exp_rets - risk_free_vector))
    return numerator / denominator
```

I would really appreciate if someone will be able to tell my if this is correct and how this can be improved!

Comment: In practice, one should never compute an inverse unless the inverse is of interest *an sich*. Rather, use `np.linalg.solve`. Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31256252/570918

Comment: The notation in that equation is somewhat cursed. Where does it come from?

Comment: Lecture provided by my professor

Answer (score 0):

First, `numpy` has making extensive use of so-called [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for speed, convenience and readability. One direct consequence of broadcasting is that the subtraction of a vector with a scalar is well-defined: the scalar value will be subtracted from all elements of the vector.

Second, as mentioned by @merv, computing the inverse of a matrix explicitly is a bad idea, because it is slow and numerically unstable in general (see [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256252/why-does-numpy-linalg-solve-offer-more-precise-matrix-inversions-than-numpy-li)). You should rather ask for the solution of the problem: `A x = b` where you are looking for `x`. To do so, you must call `np.linalg.solve(A, b)`.

Finally, the denominator is just the sum of all elements. As such, avoid doing the same computation twice, for both clarity and efficiency. Besides, you should rather use `np.sum` in this case, which is also faster and more explicit than the generic dot product `np.dot`. As a side note, I would advise you to never use `np.dot` explicitly but rather the matrix multiplication operator `@`. I find it more closer to the original written mathematical expression and therefore easier to debug.

Here is what you get in the end:

```py
def maximum_sharpe_ratio(cov, posterior_returns, risk_free_rate):
    numerator = np.linalg.solve(cov, posterior_returns - risk_free_rate)
    return numerator / np.sum(numerator)
```